# Ejabberd showing limited options in server on win10

Tags: windows, erlang, ejabberd

I have successfully installed Ejabberd on win10. when I launch the server on chrome/IE with http://localhost:5280/admin/. It shows only Virtual Hosts as option to select. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your login account is not an admin account.

Check this document, [Creating an XMPP Account for Administration](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/installation/#creating-an-xmpp-account-for-administration).

Comment: Thanku for replying. I have tried to register an account through cmd(as admin) with the following command "ejabberdctl register user1 localhost pass1" but it is returning "Error: cannot_register". Please help.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was not using the admin account for that. Thank you so much. You are awesome, man.

Answer (score -1):

```
Error occured...
```

Please check your configuration and your installation.

If you are an advanced user, you can check the logs to check what is going wrong.

The name of the current ejabberd node is ejabberd@localhost.